# Print Charts using win.print()

Tags: r, printing

THe issue I have is printing two active windows (in this case two plots) one after the other.

Please find the code below.  The win.print() command leads to a windows print dialog box. When i hit on print subsequently  i find  a "GraphAppJob" of 4 byte in the print queue and nothing is printed.  Appreciate any help.  Thanks.

```
library("quantmod")

getSymbols("YHOO",src="google")   
barChart(YHOO)    
addBBands()   
win.print()      

getSymbols("AAPL",src="google")   
barChart(AAPL)    
addBBands()   
win.print()
```

Comment: Please read [this discussion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) on how to make a good reproducible example. Right now I cannot run your code as it is...

Comment: nico, the code has been updated please see above.